# Can a complex affine variety of dimension 0 have singular points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f_1,\dots,f_n \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and let $V = \{x\in\mathbb{C}^n 
\mid f_1(x)=\dotsm=f_n(x)=0\}$ be the affine variety of their common roots. Further assume that $V$ has dimension $0$ and thus it is a finite set of points.

Theorem 8 of "Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms" (p. 521) says that the singular locus of $V$, $\Sigma = \{p\in V\mid p\text{ is a singular point of }V\}$, contains no irreducible component of $V$. My understanding is that every point of $V$ is an irreducible component since $V$ is finite. So this would imply that $V$ contains no singular points.

Is this correct? It seems too strong. Can this be seen directly from the Jacobian? My understanding is that a point $p\in V$ is singular iff $J_p(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ is invertible (in this setting).

Comment: The only possible singularity of a point is being non-reduced, so it depends on your assumptions.

Comment: Consider $n=1,\ f_1=x_1^2"

Comment: @KReiser I see, so the answer would be that the points in my variety are singular iff they have a multiplicity > 1?

Comment: I think it might be hard to see this directly via the Jacobian criterion. You need to use the characterisation of non singularity via local rings. The local ring at a point must have dimension $0$, because this dimension is the codimension of the point (which is an irreducible component). So it is Artinian by a classical result of commutative algebra. So its maximal ideal is nilpotent. On the other hand, it has no non zero nilpotents since the coordinate ring has no nilpotents. So it is a field and thus regular. So $V$ is non singular there.